# Why does my CURL post my request twice or why does my stream contains repeated request message?

Tags: c++, sockets, curl, groovy

Hi I have written code in c++ to post a request using cURL. And also I have written a code which receives this request in groovy. While testing the code it seems curl repost the request. But I am bit unsure since it does not reflected in my curl trace. On the other hand my socket stream reflects that. I could not guess where the problem lies.

Expectation:

Server side: 
If the server receives some certain request it will send some response message, if not it will simply send some integer( for the sake of testing it is integer now).

Client side: 
It will occasionally send request and get response if there is nothing to request it will simply listen to receive the message ( those integer numbers for example)

C++ Curl Call:

```
 if(curl){

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, my_trace);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        string Mydata;

        char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
        chunk.memory = (char*)malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */
        chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */
        FILE * rfp = fopen("/Users/Uma/request.xml", "r");

        if(rfp != NULL){
            cout<<"File is opened "<<endl;
        }else{
        cout<<"File is close"<<endl;

        }

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, myUrl);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);

        const char* req= "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:blz=\"http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/\">  <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body>   <blz:getBank>  <blz:blz>50070010</blz:blz> </blz:getBank>  </soapenv:Body>  </soapenv:Envelope> \n";

        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, 1L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, req);

        cout<<"requested posted "<<endl;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, reader);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, rfp);

        errbuf[0] = 0;

        /* send all data to this function  */

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,(void *)&chunk);

        curlCode = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        //  always cleanup
        if(curlCode != CURLE_OK  | curlCode != 0) {

            std::cout<<"  traced data "<<traceData<<std::endl;

            size_t len = strlen(errbuf);
            fprintf(stderr, "\nlibcurl: (%d) ", curlCode);
            if(len)
                fprintf(stderr, "%s%s", errbuf,
                        ((errbuf[len - 1] != '\n') ? "\n" : ""));
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", curl_easy_strerror(curlCode));
        } else {

            std::cout<<"CURl Code "<<curlCode<<std::endl;

                     /*
             * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
             * bytes big and contains the remote file.
             */
            std::cout<<"CURL code on error --"<<curlCode<<std::endl;
            printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (long)chunk.size);

            //cout<<"My Response ---"<<response<<endl;

            cout<<"My Chunck -- "<<chunk.memory<<endl;
        }                      

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
```

Groovy Server:

```
def server = new ServerSocket(2000)
println("Waiting for connection")

String receivedRecord 
while (true) 
{
  println " Input data "      

    server.accept() { socket ->
              socket.withStreams { input, output ->
                    def w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output))

            String message = "Connection was successful"
            println message
     def r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))

     println ("Stream ")

    String requestMessage = ""

    def cont = true
    String tempMsg;
     while (cont)
       { 
            tempMsg = r.readLine() 

            if(tempMsg == null)
            {

            cont = false

            }
            else
            {

            requestMessage = requestMessage  +   tempMsg
            }

            println (requestMessage)
            println(cont)

            tempMsg = " "
       }

     int  i = 0;

    while (i <20)
    {
        //String requestMessage = r.readLine()

        //println(" Request Received ")
        //println(requestMessage)

        String echo = "EchoRequestMsg"
        String vehicleSync = "EenheidSynchronisatieRequestMsg"

        if(requestMessage != null )
        {
                        if(requestMessage.toLowerCase().contains(echo.toLowerCase()))
            {
                println (i)
                println ("Echo Request True ")
                sendMessage("Echo", w)
                println(" Echo Message Sent ")

            }
            else if(requestMessage.toLowerCase().contains(vehicleSync.toLowerCase()))
            {     
                println (i)
                println (" Vehicle Sync True ")       
                sendMessage("VehicleSync", w)
                println(" Vehicle Sync Message Sent ")
            }
            else
            {
                println (i)
                println (" push message ")
                i++;
                sendMessage(i, w)
            }

        }


            }
        }
    }
}

def sendMessage(msg, writer) {
    println("Sending: >" + msg + "<")
    writer.writeLine(msg.toString())
    writer.flush();
}
```

Server Output:

```
 Input data 
Connection was successful
Stream 
POST / HTTP/1.1
true
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000
true
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*
true
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xml
true
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xmlSOAPAction:urn:getBank
true
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xmlSOAPAction:urn:getBankContent-Length: 251
true
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xmlSOAPAction:urn:getBankContent-Length: 251
true
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xmlSOAPAction:urn:getBankContent-Length: 251<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:blz="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/">  <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body>   <blz:getBank>  <blz:blz>50070010</blz:blz> </blz:getBank>  </soapenv:Body>  </soapenv:Envelope> 
true
```

————————> still waiting to receive further message if i terminate client it will receive one more message and start sending message to the client

Trace after I kill the client

```
groovy groovyServer.groovy 
Waiting for connection
 Input data 
 Input data 
Connection was successful
Stream 
POST / HTTP/1.1
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xml
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xmlSOAPAction:urn:getBank
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xmlSOAPAction:urn:getBankContent-Length: 256
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xmlSOAPAction:urn:getBankContent-Length: 256
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xmlSOAPAction:urn:getBankContent-Length: 256<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:blz="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/">  <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body>   <blz:getBank>  <blz:blz>50070010</blz:blz> </blz:getBank>  </soapenv:Body>  </soapenv:Envelope>
POST / HTTP/1.1Host: localhost:2000Accept: */*content-type:text/xmlSOAPAction:urn:getBankContent-Length: 256<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:blz="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/">  <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body>   <blz:getBank>  <blz:blz>50070010</blz:blz> </blz:getBank>  </soapenv:Body>  </soapenv:Envelope> 
0
 push message 
Sending: >1<
1
 push message 
Sending: >2<
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
```

Please note that there is one more request message is added after I killed client. It is just placed right above the push message starts.

Comment: Sorry, but where is the request being repeated? I see no evidence of that in your post.

Comment: When in doubt, check with wireshark.

Comment: Hi http://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit, Thanks for the reply. I have explained that in the end of my post. Once I kill  the client , the server receive body of the request again.

Comment: Added trace of the server”s received message  after I killed  the client.